# Relevance and Necessity of SNMP

Tags: snmp

**Edit:** I am in the process of designing a Java-based monitoring tool that will send back periodic "health checks" of a Java app deployed to a cluster of GlassFish servers. I am trying to figure out the best protocol for this monitoring tool to send information back to the monitoring server on.

After an initial research effort on my part, it seems like SNMP is just a protocol for monitor-type applications to communicate the "health status" of something (a part of a network, a server, a cluster, an application, etc.) to the rest of the network.

- If the above is incorrect, please correct me!!!

Assuming the generalization is more or less accurate, my next question is: **why is this a protocol!?!?**

In the age of REST/SOAP/TCP protocols, why is there the need for a standardized protocol that only fits one type of application (monitoring)? In other words, if I'm a developer assigned to building a new monitoring tool that periodically polls a server and reports on its CPU and available memory, **what advantages does SNMP give me over just POSTing to a RESTful API via plain 'ole HTTP?**

I'm *sure* I'm missing something here - I just need someone to help connect the dots! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see this has already receives a closevote. I come to superuser.com to **learn**, and have no problem with criticism, so long as it is reasonable! I would like to ask why this was closevoted!?!

Comment: I see that the closevote reason was "not a real question". I humbly diagree!! To sum this question up in 1 sentence: "*What are the benefits in this day and age of using SNMP over a REST- or SOAP-based solution?*" I believe that is **absolutely** a real question!

Comment: What's the solvable computer problem you're having?

Comment: @techie007 - please understand that this response is *not* a challenge to what you just wrote, it is merely an attempt to gain clarity as to where I should post questions like this in the future. Is "solvable computer problem" *really* the definitive criteria for a SuperUser question? Because, that's pretty vague, and would include StackOverflow, ServerFault, and most other tech-centric StackExchange sites. If it is, then I say this is a solvable problem: I want to when and where I should use SNMP. If it is not the criteria, then what is/are? That answer will determine *where* this belongs!

Comment: From the SU [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: Please see my edit - it includes my actual problem at hand and takes some of the "mystery" out of my question. Hopefully it turns this from a theoretical question into a practical one.

Comment: Even after your edit, your still asking for 'the best' protocol to use, which is generally only answerable with opinion.

Comment: True, but I think its succinct and specific enough to merit being on SuperUser as a legitimate question. If enough other users side with your opinion, I'll respect the SU community to close this.

Comment: One other argument here: this isn't a "best" (opinion-driven) question, even though the word "*best*" actually appears in my edit! I am asking for someone to list the **specific** advantages SNMP has over a more modern approach, and that is: (1) absolutely finite and answerable, and (2) not subjective. Again, I stand by this as a legitimate question. And although it was only asked 8 hours ago and that is by no means a sufficient amount of time for a solid response, I think its lack of an answer does indicate that my instincts are correct: SNMP offers no such advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*the need for a **standardized** protocol*... Cause it's standardised? It also predates HTTP (1988 vs 1991). REST would have been with HTTP 1.0, 1996. Once something is in use, it's often easier to stick with it, if only for legacy support.

In response to your edit: Do you want/need other, pre-existing tools to be able to communicate with your application? If not, you can use whatever method you feel like, but you will need to use your own monitoring tools. If yes, you'll need to use something that is already commonly supported, *such as* SNMP.

Comment: So in your mind it doesn't give me any benefits *over* a REST- or SOAP-based solution?

Comment: @AdamTannon SNMP is more established, and has considerably less overhead to set up than anything involving HTTP.

Comment: Again, not arguing here, just trying to understand.  With frameworks like Jersey and my own homegrown libraries, and can get a RESTful web service up and running with 30 lines of code. Can you clarify what you mean by "overhead"?

Comment: @Bob - as the only answer-er I'd be happy to give you the "green check" if can you cite specific advantages that SNMP has over more modern (REST/SOAP/etc.) approaches.

Comment: @AdamTannon It's probably better that you wait for someone else to answer. I'm not familiar enough with SNMP, nor other approaches. All I can say is SNMP has been in use for a longer time, and it's standard enough you can find a generic SNMP logger and expect it to work.

Comment: http://www.snmp.com/protocol/snmp_rfcs.shtml contains comprehensive requirements and implementation methods for SNMP.  There's nothing stopping you or anyone from wrapping SNMP in a RESTful or SOAP based interface to consolidate and administrate the SNMP data, not unlike Nagios or HP OpenView, that's fine, insofar as the basic SNMP control structures remain for those who wish to implement their own ideas as to how best to manage their network devices.

Answer (score 1):

Far from being an expert on this, I would suggest the following:

SNMP has one fixed Management Information Base containing hierarchies of classes of information (e.g. actual bandwidth of the interfaces). As such you can easily add nodes to the network you are monitoring, without a lot of configuring.

Even more there are some machines where you might have no access to. (Either because of permissions or because they are simplistic routers.) In this case SNMP will be the easy way to get and set configuration parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
RESTful API via plain 'ole HTTP
```

This has the following dependencies:

- an HTTP server
- a backend process invoked by that server that maintains state
- enough memory, bandwidth, and storage resources to handle all possible concurrent connection attempts on top of what the device is supposed to be doing (we're assuming you want your device to do other things than respond to status requests)
- and the subdependencies of all frameworks needed to implement the above, if frameworks are used (i.e. if your backend process is written in Perl, then that's more resources needed, etc.)

The above is trivial these days (and many devices, etc. have HTTP servers built in these days), but when SNMP was developed it wasn't.

SNMP is a lot simpler and can be handled easier by low-resource embedded devices (think older switches, etc.), and the software that responds to SNMP requests can be written easier with less chance of security vulnerabilities.